# How can I create a register route in express.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a `REST API` and I'm able to connect to the server and database.
The problem is that when I try to add a user to the database in `Postman` it saves the user in the database but, the user is undefined. I get an empty object in my `MongoDB`.

Exaple of result:

```
_id:ObjectId("5e8e108487d47c2d87872f20")
                   date:2020-04-08T17:43:29.445+00:00
                  __v:0
```

Model

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        first_name: {type: String, require: true},
        last_name: {type: String, require: true},
        email: {type: String, require: true},
        password: {type: String, require: true},
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}  
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Routes

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    const User = require('../models/user');

    router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
        const today = new Date();
        const userData = {
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            created: today
        }

        User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
        })
        .then(user => {
            if(!user){
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    userData.password = hash
                    User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json({status: user.email + ' registered!'})
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send('error: ' + err)
                    })
                })
            } else {
                res.json({error: ' user already exists'})
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
    })

    module.exports = router;
```

Server

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;

// parse requests
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Connecting to DB
mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully');
})

const usersRouter = require('./api/routes/users');

app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: which of them is executed then or catch? =>>>>User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json({status: user.email + ' registered!'})
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send('error: ' + err)
                    })

Comment: How to get this "user already exists" message on browser console.I tried many timme but i am not able to get the message.

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand the code there is one issue

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {type: String, require: true},
    last_name: {type: String, require: true},
    email: {type: String, require: true},
    password: {type: String, require: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}  
});
```

This has date property but actually you are using `created` in API call. you should use the exact name as of model(recommended) or try `strict: false` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        first_name: {type: String, required: true},
        last_name: {type: String, required: true},
        email: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Routes

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const userData = {
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }

  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          userData.password = hash
          const newUser = new User(userData);
          newUser.save()
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ status: user.email + ' registered!' })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.send('error: ' + err)
            })
        })
      } else {
        res.json({ error: ' user already exists' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

In the model i used `required` instead of `require` and for adding a new user i created a new object of the model and then used the `.save()` method.

Comment: after adding your changes i get this error message on postman:error:  ValidationError: first_name: Path `first_name` is required., last_name: Path `last_name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required.

Comment: solved it i was missing bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

Comment: yes right I didnt check your server.js file, you need that so you can access req.body. The values you mentioned got undefined because missing bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), so that the ValidationError occurred.

Answer (score 0):

In your Model, just change change the "date" key to "created" instead. Also, to require a key, you should write `required:true` instead of `require:true`. Here is the Model code that should work:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {type: String, required: true},
    last_name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```